# Given a sequence of positive integers A and an integer T, return true if a continuous sequence of A sums up to exactly T

Tags: java, algorithm, array, interview-questions

Here is [the source of the question](http://www.careercup.com/question?id=6305076727513088), and my solution is below.
Did I determine the worst case correctly?
If you find any input where it doesn't work, please let me know.

```
public class Main {

    /*
     * http://www.careercup.com/question?id=6305076727513088
     * 
     * Worst case: O(2*n)
     * [ 1, 3, 4, 1, 0, 23 ] and k == 23. We have to iterate over the array twice:
     * 
     * 1. We sum up all the elements [0, n - 1], n - the array size
     * 2. We subtract all the elements [0, n - 2]
     */
    static boolean findSum(int[] array, int k) {
        int i = 0;
        int start = i;
        int sum = 0;
        for (; i < array.length;) {
            if (array[i] > k) {
                i += 2;
                start = i;
                sum = 0;
                continue;
            }
            if (sum < k) {
                sum += array[i];
                i++;
            }
            while (sum > k) {
                sum -= array[start];
                start++;
            }
            if (sum == k) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

}
```

**Unit tests.**

```
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

import org.junit.Test;

public class MainTest {

    @Test
    public void testFindSum() {
        // k exists in the input array

        // It's the first element
        assertTrue(Main.findSum(new int[] { 15, 4, 6, 10, 2, 11 }, 15));
        // It's in the middle
        assertTrue(Main.findSum(new int[] { 1, 4, 15, 10, 2, 11 }, 15));
        // It's the last element
        assertTrue(Main.findSum(new int[] { 1, 4, 0, 10, 2, 15 }, 15));

        // k equals to the sum of a few elements

        // The elements are at the beginning
        assertTrue(Main.findSum(new int[] { 10, 4, 4, 10, 2, 16 }, 14));

        // The elements are at the middle
        assertTrue(Main.findSum(new int[] { 1, 4, 4, 10, 2, 16 }, 14));

        // The elements are at the end
        assertTrue(Main.findSum(new int[] { 1, 4, 4, 1, 1, 13 }, 14));

        // k is the sum of all the elements
        assertTrue(Main.findSum(new int[] { 1, 4, 4, 1, 4 }, 14));

        // There is an element which is greater than k
        // It's in the middle
        assertFalse(Main.findSum(new int[] { 1, 42, 4, 1, 4 }, 14));

        // It's the first element
        assertFalse(Main.findSum(new int[] { 42, 1, 4, 1, 4 }, 14));

        // It's the last element
        assertFalse(Main.findSum(new int[] { 1, 0, 4, 1, 42 }, 14));

        // Last but one
        assertFalse(Main.findSum(new int[] { 1, 0, 4, 144, 12 }, 14));

        // Worst case
        assertTrue(Main.findSum(new int[] { 1, 3, 4, 1, 0, 23 }, 23));

    }

}
```

[GitHub](https://github.com/MaksimDmitriev/Sum-Adjacent)

Comment: It doesn't seem to work for this input: assertFalse(Main.findSum(new int[] { 17, 4, 1, 5, 4, 1 }, 13));

Answer (score 13, accepted):

#### Approach and complexity

It is a pleasure to tell you this: Excellent!

Your approach is precisely what I had in mind when I read the challenge description (before looking at your code).

#### Unit tests

Excellent that you have unit tests! Definitely helps in checking if it's possible to clean up your method. My only suggestion would be to [make them Parameterized](https://github.com/junit-team/junit/wiki/Parameterized-tests), which should be a lot more helpful if one or more of them fails.

#### Some simplifications

I was slightly confused by this code at first:

```
if (array[i] > k) {
    i += 2;
    start = i;
    sum = 0;
    continue;
}
```

Then I noticed that it checked if the *value at the current position in the array* was more than the target `k`. Then I figured: "Why use this as a special case? The rest of the code should be able to handle this." And it does. Removing this part of the code doesn't change a thing on your unit tests either. While I can understand why you are doing this (it probably does help a bit with performance in some cases), I don't think it's worth it. Don't add unnecessary special-cases.

---

Next thing I noticed is that `sum < k` will always be true. Therefore, that `if` can be removed and be simply:

```
sum += array[i];
i++;
```

And now, speaking of `i++`, we can transform this for-loop into a traditional for loop, by adding both the initialization and the iteration to it:

```
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
```

This makes it:

```
static boolean findSum(final int[] array, final int k) {
    int start = 0;
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        sum += array[i];
        while (sum > k) {
            sum -= array[start];
            start++;
        }
        if (sum == k) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

#### Nitpicks

`k` is a bad variable name. `target` or `targetSum` would be better.

I am not a big fan of `int start = i;` in your original code. `start` is not dependent on `i` at all. They start at the same value, sure, but it's more clear to set `start = 0;`

Your method lacks an accessibility modifier, you probably want to make it a `public` method.

#### Overall

Well done!

Comment: In this context `i` is also a bad variable name, as it is unclear what relation the index `i` has to the index `start`. `end` would be a better name, or you could use `last` and change `start` to `first`.

Comment: Is the unnecessary part even correct? Unless I'm missing something, `i += 2;` would skip the next element without reason, failing in cases where this next element is necessary to achieve the sum (like  `Main.findSum(new int[] { 10, 8, 1 }, 9)`).

Comment: @OxTaz You are right, that does break it. I tried to find a flaw in it, but I must have done something wrong in my testing. May I suggest you write an answer pointing out that flaw? Should earn you some reputation :)

Answer (score 11):

I had a bit of a longer answer in the works, but Simon's answer covers almost every point I intended to cover.

The one thing I can add is this:

#### Variable's scope should be as limited as possible.

#### Variable's scope should be no wider than necessary.

We don't use `start` or `sum` outside of the `for` loop, so let's declare them in the initialization statement of the `for` loop, making their scope as narrow as possible.

```
for (int sum = 0, start = 0, i = 0; i < array.length; ++i) { // ...
```

---

Also, I think the method name needs some work.  `findSum` makes me think the method will in some way sum up the arguments and return an `int`, so that it returns a `boolean` is confusing.  We could try on the following method name and see if it fits:

```
public static boolean containsSummationSequence(final int[] array, final int targetSum)
```

Answer (score 6):

The unnecessary part (as explained in [Simon's answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/86340/70002)) also has a flaw:

```
    if (array[i] > k) {
        i += 2;
        start = i;
        sum = 0;
        continue;
    }
```

Here, `i += 2;` not only ignores the current element as intended, but also skips the next element. So, it will fail if this next element is necessary to achieve the sum, like:

```
assertTrue(Main.findSum(new int[] { 10, 8, 1 }, 9)); // Fails: 8 is skipped
assertTrue(Main.findSum(new int[] { 20, 15 }, 15));  // Fails: 15 is skipped
```

Answer (score 5):

One suggestion for your method signature, you can consider using varargs on the integer sequence, so that you leave the implicit `int[]` declaration to the compiler/JVM:

```
public static boolean findSum(int targetSum, int... array) {
    ...
}
```

To add on to [Simon's point of parameterized testing](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/86340/27975), I have previously compared this feature for both JUnit and TestNG frameworks, hopefully it gives you a better idea of how it can be done: [Match Simple Sentence or Partial Sentence](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/60247/match-simple-sentence-or-partial-sentence/60299#60299)

Answer (score 1):

Here is another possible solution, however it seems logically equivalent to Simon's answer.

```
public static boolean findSum(int[] array, int k) {
  int a = 0, b = 0, sum = 0;

  while(b < array.length) {
    if(sum < k) sum += array[b++];
    else if(sum > k) sum -= array[a++];
    else return true;
  }
  return sum == k;
}
```

Comment: This is the wrong answer: try {23,5,4,7,2,11} & sum 20.